# Android onClickListener to delete itself

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout

I have a custom LinearLayout class called LabelButton that contains a button and a TextView. I want to have the button's onclick listener delete the LabelButton. How can I pass something from an object of LabelButton to my Activity class, telling my main layout to remove that LabelButton?

```
public class LabelButton extends LinearLayout {
  private OnClickListener onClick;
    public LabelButton(Context context, final String text) {
        super(context);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        View labelView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.button_label, this );
        TextView textView = (TextView) labelView.findViewById( R.id.textLabelText);
        textView.setText( text );
        Button button = (Button) labelView.findViewById( R.id.buttonCancelLabel );

        onClick = new OnClickListener( ) {
          public void onClick( View v ) {
            System.out.println("Button: " + text + " clicked");
            // do something here to remove this button
          }
        };
        button.setOnClickListener( onClick );
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();

    }

}
```

In my Activity class, I add the LabelButtons to a list like this...

```
//labelButtons is a List of LabelButtons

LabelButton labelButton = new LabelButton( getApplicationContext( ),
            txtBagLabel.getText( ).toString( ) );
        labelButtons.add( labelButton );
```

Comment: maybe you can try this : labelView.setVisibility(View.GONE) , but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

`((ViewGroup) LabelButton.this.getParent()).removeView(LabelButton.this);`

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways. One, you can set the visibility to GONE on the button you want to remove.

```
labelButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

If you're doing this from inside the button (i.e. it wants to hide *itself*) you might try

```
LabelButton.this.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

The second way is to get a reference to the parent view and call

```
parentView.remove(child);
```

Where child is of course the reference to your LabelButton object.

Comment: How do I get the reference to the element from its parent?

Answer (score 0):

Make your button object final and then you can reference it from inside your `OnClickListener` and maybe change its visibility or remove it from its view.

Answer (score 0):

You can alias 'this' to a class variable like so:

```
ViewGroup self = this;
```

And then you can do the following:

```
onClick = new OnClickListener( ) {
    public void onClick( View v ) {
        System.out.println("Button: " + text + " clicked");
        // do something here to remove this button
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) getParent();
        parent.removeView(self);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this:

```
 onClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           //remove this button
            ((LinearLayout)v.getParent()).removeView(v);              
        }
 };
```

then set button that listener

```
 button.setOnClickListener( onClick );
```

Answer (score 0):

Same thing in KOTLIN:

```
findViewById<View>(R.id.removeWidget)?.setOnClickListener {
        (parent as ViewGroup).removeView(this)
    }
```